# Redefine ArcCot to be inverse of range [0, Pi]

Tags: functions, customization, trigonometry

Mathematica implements `ArcCot` function as an inverse to `Cot` on range `[-Pi/2, Pi/2]`. I personally prefer the other definition (as it's used in courses I attend). Is it possible to redefine the function?

Current implementation:

[image: range -Pi/2 to Pi/2]

My prefered implementation:

[image: range 0 to Pi]

(images taken from http://intmstat.com/blog/2011/04/cotx_2.gif)

Comment: example of redefining a function, utilizing the original:  http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2013/Sep/msg00006.html

Comment: @george2079 awesome, thanks, this completes the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long comment / warning..

Heres anotherlink:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656

Which in this case is implemented as:

```
Unprotect[ArcCot];
ArcCot[args___ ] :=
Block[{$inAcot = True}, Mod[ArcCot[args], Pi]] /; ! TrueQ[$inAcot]
Protect[ArcCot]
```

And seems to work ..

```
{ArcCot[1], ArcCot[-1]} -> {Pi/4, 3 Pi /4}
```

However in some unexpected circumstances we fall back on the original..

```
GraphicsRow[{
   ListPlot[Table[ {x, ArcCot[ x]} , {x, -5, 5, .2}], Joined -> True], 
   ListPlot[Table[ {x, ArcCot[ x]} , {x, -5, 5, .02}], Joined -> True],
   Plot[ ArcCot[ x], {x, -5, 5}]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

`Table[]` uses the new definition in the first case and the original in the second.. go figure.

```
  First@Table[ {x, ArcCot[ x]} , {x, -1, 0, .01}]  -> {-1., 2.35619}
  First@Table[ {x, ArcCot[ x]} , {x, -1, 0, .001}] -> {-1., -0.785398}
```

Same results with this:

```
 Unprotect[ArcCot];
 ArcCot[args___ ] := Pi/2 - ArcTan[args];
 Protect[ArcCot];
```

( 9.0.0.0 / windows..)

Comment: Falling back to the original behaviour is most probably due to auto-compilation, which uses the built in functions. This can be circumvented by using an additional `Evaluate` or in the case of `Plot` by the option `Evaluated->True`.

Comment: @sebhofer confirmed that does fix things.  Still you need to wonder where else this issue might show up.

Comment: It's well known that compilation does not use user defined rules for built in functions (at least for some of them, I'm not sure if it's true for all of them). On the other hand I don't think it's surprising that things like this happen when you redefine protected functions. An easy fix is to define your own...

Answer (score 6):

You could use `ArcTan[t, 1]` instead of `ArcCot[t]`

Comment: Oh this is so easy it's awesome. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Just take the result mode Pi?

```
  myArcCot[n_] := Mod[ArcCot[n], Pi]
  N@myArcCot[-Pi/4]
  (*2.23657007682325*)
```

And if you want, you can change the definition of ArcCot by removing the read protection on it and redfining it, but I would think making you own wrapper would be more safe.

Comment: Thanks, the issue though is that I can't manage to redefine the original function. `Unprotect[ArcCot]; ArcCot[x_] := Mod[ArcCot[x], Pi]` does not work for obvious reason.

Comment: @MikulasDite, sure and that is why I said it is better to make a wrapper around it as I have shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is

```
Block[{ArcCot = π/2 - ArcTan[#] &}, Plot[ArcCot[x], {x, -10, 10}]]
```

[image]